# Conjugate of element in connected fMR group is indecomposable?

Tags: logic, model-theory

In my studies I have seen these results that do not make sense to me. Will be grateful for any advice. I will also give my ideas of why they could be true.

1) For connected group $G$ of finite Morley rank, and $x\in G$,  $x^{G}$ is indecomposable.

2) If $x$ is not in the centre of $G$, then $x^{G}\cup \{1_{G}\}$ is indecomposable.

Here if a set $W$ is (left)-indecomposable it means that for definable subgroup $H$ of $G$ and subset $W\subseteq G$, $\{gH \in G/H| gH\cap W \neq \emptyset \}$ can't have finite cardinal $>1$. So indecomposable means both left and right-indecomposable with this definition.

So my try for the first part:

$x^{G}$ cannot have finite index in $G$ since $G$ connected. Then assume (trying to contradict) that $\{gH \in G/H| gH\cap W \neq \emptyset \}$ has finite cardinal $>1$. This means that a finite collection $g_{1}H,...,g_{m}H$ has nonempty intersection with $x^{G}$ so $x^{g}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{m}g_{i}H$. I am not sure how to proceed from there but I want to show that connectedness is contradicted by how the finite cardinal $>1$.

For the second part am a bit stuck. Was thinking maybe to use the same method as the first part, but I have not made use of the fact that $x$ is not in the centre of $G$ which mean I cannot just reuse this method?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: 1. You write "$x^G$ cannot have finite index in $G$, since $G$ is connected." But this doesn't make sense, since $x^G$ is not a subgroup in general. 2. Do you know the theorem (a special case of Theorem 2.8 in Poizat's *Stable Groups*) that if $X\subseteq G$ is fixed setwise by conjugation, then to show $X$ is indecomposable, it suffices to check on *normal* subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Thank you. I was actually unaware of this result by Poizat. I will study some of those results in his book and see if I can make some progress.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I can now see normality gives us both left and right-indecomposability, so I only would have to check left, but I'm lost about how else I should use it. I end up with the finite union of cosets but this isn't even a group so there isn't a clear way further. Do I need to restart my method completely differently?